# Why can't I go twice through the rows of a CSV provider?

Tags: f#, sequence, type-providers

In some languages after one goes through a lazy sequence it becomes exhausted. That is not the case with `F#`:

```
let mySeq = seq [1..5]

mySeq |> Seq.iter (fun x -> printfn "%A" <| x)
mySeq |> Seq.iter (fun x -> printfn "%A" <| x)

1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
```

However, it looks like one can go only once through the rows of a CSV provider:

```
open FSharp.Data

[<Literal>]
let foldr = __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + @"\data\"

[<Literal>]
let csvPath = foldr + @"AssetInfoFS.csv"

type AssetsInfo = CsvProvider<Sample=csvPath,
                              HasHeaders=true,
                              ResolutionFolder=csvPath,
                              AssumeMissingValues=false,
                              CacheRows=false>

let assetInfo = AssetsInfo.Load(csvPath)
assetInfo.Rows |> Seq.iter (fun x -> printfn "%A" <| x) // Works fine 1st time
assetInfo.Rows |> Seq.iter (fun x -> printfn "%A" <| x) // 2nd time exception
```

Why does that happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this [link](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvFile.html) on the CSV Parser, the CSV Type Provider is built on top of the CSV Parser. The CSV Parser works in streaming mode, most likely by calling a method like [`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx), which will throw an exception if the enumerator is enumerated a second time. The CSV Parser also has a `Cache` method. Try setting CacheRows=true (or leaving it out of the declaration since its default value is true) to avoid this issue

```
CsvProvider<Sample=csvPath,
            HasHeaders=true,
            ResolutionFolder=csvPath,
            AssumeMissingValues=false,
            CacheRows=true>
```

Answer (score 1):

The sequence iterator stays put where you point it; after the first loop, that is the end of the sequence.

If you want it to go back to the beginning, you have to set it there.